# How to use izPack to create an installer

Tags: java, izpack

Hi I have installed izPack in linux operating system.
I have my own java application in jar format. I want to create a installer of that jar file for a linux operating system.
I want to display license agreement when some one wants to install using that installer

So can anyone tell me the step by step approach to create installer using izpack.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating an installer with IzPack is fairly straightforward and well-documented. Unfortunately the specifics are highly dependent on the product to be installed, so your best bet is to read the [documentation](http://izpack.org/documentation/) and look at the [sample](http://izpack.org/documentation/sample-install-definition.html).

Comment: Hi I have created both install-definition.xml for my project but how to create the executable file. Do I need to deploy anywhere.

Comment: Both links are dead

Comment: Use this link "https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/overview" it is an active link

Answer (score 4):

Hello 
In the link below you will find a nice help about izpack installer.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89

Link below contains a detailed pdf to make installer with izpack.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?attachment_id=112

cheers

Imran tariq

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you already have the install.xml as documented at the izpack homepage

So the next step would be to compile the installer.jar from it.

Either you follow the getting started guide from izpack or you use a plugin to include the izpack action to your deployment process.

There is a plugin for maven
(see here 
http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/usage.html for how to use it)
and there also is one for ant, its documented at the izpack page.
http://izpack.org/documentation/sample-install-definition.html

Answer (score 2):

Visit Here for Simple [Example](http://sonalimendis.blogspot.in/2010/05/write-installer-with-izpack.html)  .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add.

1. License.txt file with the same level of bin directory. Now add the following line to panel
2. add panel tage like "panel classname="LicencePanel" "  in panels tag
3. add file tage like "file src="Licence.txt" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" " in "packet" tag.